# How to see fields in data (subscribe) in Angular

Tags: angular, subscribe, ngoninit

I want to choose the Objects that I want to put in the tasks array according to IdEmployee
Im trying to display the content of data (in which there is the field "IdEmployee"), but when I display it, I can see : data.IdEmployee = undefined

In the html file, I can see the entire array from my database

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-tasks',
  templateUrl: './display-tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-tasks.component.css']
})
export class DisplayTasksComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  tasks:any=[]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshList();
  }

  refreshList(){
    this.http.get<any>(environment.API_URL+'task')
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.tasks=data;
      alert("data.IdEmployee = "+data.IdEmployee)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the result for console.log(data); please?
You might be traversing JSON (Or the response) in a wrong way.

Comment: What is the type of "data" ? "data" may not have a property named idEmployee.

Comment: the type of data is object, so if I display console.log(data), I can see [Object object]

Comment: Please do console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) so as to print the content of the object

Comment: Now I see the content of the database : [{"Id":1,"IdEmployee":11111111,"TaskText":"Prepare task1","AssignDate":"2021-07-07T00:00:00","DueDate":"2021-08-08T00:00:00"}]

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an array of objects as data.

Try:

```js
alert("data.IdEmployee = " + tasks[0].IdEmployee)
```

This way you are fetching the IdEmployee of the first object in your array.

If you always get back just one object, you might want to consider changing the back-end to just return an object instead of an array of objects.

(I doubt you want to iterate over an array and alert all the IdEmployee's?)